# Feedback on "...as soon as ..."

Tags: conjunctions

I want to know if the following sentence is correct:

> Therefore, the order of X will be determined as
> soon as the following results are proved:

My aim is to determine the order of an object, X. For this, I need to prove other results. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It appears to be grammatical and reasonably idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is very passive in voice. There's a glut of helping verbs that I'd recommend you avoid, especially since this appears to be somewhat-academic. Other small note, I think you should use **proven** over **proved** here. **Proved** would be used when the *proving* is a complete event in the past. **Proven** implies that they may still ongoing.

If you're trying to get someone off your back about a deadline, maybe start off with the prerequisite events: "As soon as the results are proven, we will determine the order of X."

Or if you like your current structure: "Our team will determine the order of X as soon as the the following results are proven."

Last note - the way you have written the determining implies that *anyone* may be determining the order of X. If you know, just say it. "Me/I" or "we" or "the study team" or whatever it may be gives the reader more context with very little extra writing.

Active, concise writing is always the goal!

Comment: The controversy over the choice between "proved" and "proven" does not appear to be so much one of meaning as one of "regional" choice: "proven" is preferred in Scotland and the US, albeit  _The Chicago Manual of Style_ recommends "proved", and "proved " is preferred in the UK. Both are considered correct. https://www.dictionary.com/e/proved-vs-proven/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! It is a scientific paper, and so I tried to avoid to use "we will determine the order...".

Comment: Quite right, @LPH! I didn't realize Chicago recommended it, but I guess I should also disclose that I'm generally not a fan of Chicago style (unless we're talking pizza).

And @CelineHarumi, when I wrote technical papers, my advisors recommended that I use objective terms like "the team" instead of "my/our team" so that you could be very clear while also writing in 3rd person and an active voice.